# communication between client side and server side application

Tags: java, servlets, summarization

I am working on a project of DBpedia entity summarization. I want first to turn a project API called SUMMARUM. In this project the author make two parts: a client part and server application part:

Server side: https://github.com/athalhammer/summaServer
Client side: https://github.com/athalhammer/summaClient

Now, I am reading some tutorials about servlet which aim to develop a server application. And from what I understand, a servlet life cycle can be defined from a set of functions: `init()`, `service()`, `doGet()`, `doPost()`, `destroy()`, ... and extends `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`.

The problem now, is that I didn't find the above functions in the summaServer project and I don't understand how to make a connection between the server side and the client side.

Comment: There is no servlet class. It's using AJAX on the client side to communicate with REST API endpoints on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses `jax-rs`, not pure servlets
https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html

Answer (score 1):

As Dmitry already answered, summaServer uses [jax-rs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html) where the endpoint doesn't have to extend `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`.

What fooled you is that you can use use servlets as web service endpoints and the tutorials you read certainly do that. I would say this is the old fashion way.

Now, jax-rs and its annotation remove all the boilerplate you had to implement otherwise.

Comment: Thanks to all. I get an idea about the jax-rs, and now i can't fix how the server side and the client side communicate between them, i mean what are functions that make connection between the both side.